# Dark Transparent Layer on Inactive Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface

Like Some Webpages, I need one feature in My VB.NET WinForm Application.

While A Child Form is Active the Parent Form in the Background should have transparent dark layer on It, So that User Can easily focus on Active Form.

If Parent form Itself got activated, that dark layer should not appear.

Initial Idea was to use Panel Control but Unfortunately It doesnt have Opacity Property.

Answer (score 0):

The Form has an opacity property though:

[Form.Opacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity.aspx)

Just set this to 0.25 On the Deactivate Event and 1 on the Activate Event

Comment: So when i create a new form in the parent form i sing up for the activate and deactivate events and set the opacity there? nothing happened for me there